# Универсальный селектор и font-size

Tags: css

Не совсем до понимаю происходящее:
С помощью универсального селектора `*` произвел сброс параметров в том числе и `font-size: 0;`, далее в разметке для блока заголовка установил  размер шрифта, к примеру, 16рх. В этом блоке находятся несколько заголовков и как я понимаю они должны унаследовать размер шрифта у родителя... но на деле получается 0.
Вопрос: При использовании `*`, в данном случае, каждому тегу необходимо задавать размер шрифта, так как свойство будет наследоваться не от родителя,а браться по правилу "для всех тегов" и для переопределения необходимо задавать явно свойство каждому элементу?

Comment: Сорри. Я вообще почти ничего не понял :) У вас проблема в том что * имеет больше приоритет чем класс?

Comment: Нет, не в этом. С помощью `*` сбросил размер шрифта, далее для блока имеющего некий контент задал размер, но теги внутри блока не наследуют это правило и приходиться задавать его явно тегам напрямую

Comment: А вы указали `font-size: inherit` что бы те наследовали? Можно сделать что-то типа `div * {font-size: inherit;}`

Comment: Вы меня не поняли, размер шрифта наследуется по умолчанию, смысл писать inherit, в таком случае и явно его указать не проблема.... Я хотел лишь узнать принцип работы такого поведения, на примере универсального селектора и размера шрифта(правило которое наследуется)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ибо селектор * становиться важнее стандартного значения. Что бы указать что внутренние теги должны следовать родительскому размеру нужно превысить приоритет звездочки. Например:

CSS

```
* {font-size: 10px;}
.txt {font-size: 20px;}
.txt * {font-size: inherit;}
```

HTML

```
текст вне
<div class="txt">
текст 0
<span>текст 1</span>
<strong>текст 2</strong>
<div>текст 3</div>
</div>
```

Отобразит внутренний контент размером 20px как указано в классе `txt` и все будет наследоваться, а этот пример:

CSS

```
* {font-size: 10px;}
.txt {font-size: 20px;}
```

HTML

```
текст вне
<div class="txt">
текст 0
<span>текст 1</span>
<strong>текст 2</strong>
<div>текст 3</div>
</div>
```

Отобразит весь текст размера 10px как указано в селекторе *.

Comment: font-size: 10;  - может так font-size: 10px?

Comment: @soledar10 работает в любом варианте. Но да, подразумевалось все-таки 10px.

Comment: Если вы проверяли без doctype, тогда да, браузер будет вычислять в px, а если с doctype - будет ошибка invalid property value

Comment: @soledar10  верно, это был пробник даже без <html>